# Using php class for storing and grouping data to each person in array using different IDs

Tags: php

I have SQL exercise where I should convert table data into a print sentence where every person has phone numbers. For example

```
Alice: n1  (person ID here is 1)
Alice: n2 (person ID here is 1)
Alice: n5 (person ID here is 4)
Bob: n3 (person ID here is 2)
Carol: n4 (person ID here is 3)
```

But instead `Alice: n1 and Alice: n2` it should be `Alice: n1, n2`. `Alice: n5` has a different ID and we aren't limited to a unique name. So we should get :

```
Alice: n1, n2 
Alice: n5 
Bob: n3 
Carol: n4
```

I'm pretty sure I missed something since I'm getting each person phone(s) separately in `$personList`

```
require_once 'Person.php';

function statementToPersonList($stmt) {

    $dictionary = [];
    $personList = [];

    foreach ($stmt as $row) {

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $number = $row['number'];

        $person = new Person($id, $name);
        $key = array_search($id, array_column($personList, 'id'));
        if (!$key) {
            $person ->addPhone($number);
            $personList[] = $person;
        }else{
            $personList[$key] ->addPhone($number);
        }
    }
    return $personList;
```

`addPhone()` is just a function in Person class file

```
public function addPhone($phone) {
        $this->phones[] = $phone;
    }
```

Maybe I should use up this `$dictionary = []` array, to store values, but I'm still confused how should I do it then. Cannot use database to handle the concatenation.

Comment: `array_search` will return 0 if the ID is found, so you should test `$key === false` instead of `!$key`. Also, does your `Person` class have public properties or magic accessors? And does the same person name twice mean the same ID twice?

Comment: You are better off letting the database handle the concatenation. Have a look at the mySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: @Jeto The same person name twice means that they have different ID's, first two 'n1' and 'n2' have the same ID's, but 'n5' has different. Person class has public id, name and phones which is an array and the also public function __construct(id, name) besides addPhone(phone) function. We have just given database with values so there isn't a problem with not having an ID at all :)

Comment: @jeff thank you for this option, but unfortunately, we are not allowed to do this at the moment :(

Comment: @ChloeJ7 You should edit your question to specify IDs. Like "1 Alice n1", "1 Alice n2", "2 Alice n5", etc. Otherwise there is no way to see that they have different identifiers (or only by guessing).

Comment: @Jeto, I'll do that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more efficient way to do this would be to index your array by ID. Your code becomes:

```
/**
 * @return Person[]
 */
function statementToPersonList(iterable $stmt): array
{
    $personList = [];

    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $number = $row['number'];

        if (!isset($personList[$id])) {
            $personList[$id] = new Person($id, $name);
        }

        $personList[$id]->addPhone($number);
    }

    return $personList;
}
```

Note: you can also `return array_values($personList)` if you don't want the array indexed by ID when retrieving it.

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/YBFdQ)**

Comment: Close enough, but at the moment it adds second Alice as well to first Alice array, right? Since Alice: n1, n2 and Alice: n5, should be separate :D  but getting Alice: n1, n2, n5

Comment: Your question is quite unclear then. Why didn't you show the "IDs" at all? I'm gonna edit my answer, give me a minute. Edit: answer edited.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that,:(  if you give me a right heads up to what I should be asking then I'd be happy tho change my text/question what ever is needed ;)

Comment: No problems. I've edited my answer, this should now be grouped by ID, so let me know. I'll add a suggestion to the question's comments above.